# creating a new variable in directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a brand new scope variable in the directive. It just consists of simplified version of my JSON data. I want to avoid processing complex JSON objects in the HTML hence I am trying to create a JSON data structure known only to directive.

I want to know HOW can we create a brand new variable ?

I tried something like this and Angularjs throws a bunch of errors in the console. I don't know exactly what is it complaining about.

```
angularApp.directive('viewPersonData', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          addressData: '=',
          professionalData: '=',
          creditData: '=',
         },
       templateUrl: 'viewPersonData.html',
      link: linker
    };

function linker(scope, element, attrs) {

 scope.showData= function() {
                if( something) 
               { 

              //defining a new scope variable
              scope.employees = [];

                var firstname = "John";
                var lastname = "Smith";
                var employee = {
                    "firstname": firstname,
                    "lastname": lastname
                }

                scope.employees.push(employee);

                 return true;
              }

        }
}

});
```

Even though HTML template ( viewPersonData.html ) does retrieve the employee data through below code.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <tr>
                    <td class="alnLt b" >{{employee.firstname}}</td>

                    <td class="alnLt b">{{employee.lastname}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
```

I see following errors in the console :

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"John\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"Smith\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"John\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"Smith\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"John\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"Smith\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"John\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"Smith\"; oldVal: undefined"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 12; oldVal: 11","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"John\"; oldVal: undefined","fn: function (context) {\r\n          try {\r\n            for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\r\n              if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\r\n                part = part(context);\r\n                if (part == null || part == undefined) {\r\n                  part = '';\r\n                } else if (typeof part != 'string') {\r\n                  part = toJson(part);\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n              concat[i] = part;\r\n            }\r\n            return concat.join('');\r\n          }\r\n          catch(err) {\r\n            var newErr = new Error('Error while interpolating: ' + text + '\\n' + err.toString());\r\n            $exceptionHandler(newErr);\r\n          }\r\n        }; newVal: \"Smith\"; oldVal: undefined"]]
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (angular.js:8841:61)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (angular.js:9012:24)
    at done (angular.js:10265:45)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10449:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:10404:11)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "brand new variable"? You are already creating an isolated scope, so you should have access to your parameters in the directive. But I don't understand, what seems to be the problem..

Comment: @CarlosPliego: Updated with the error.

Comment: @Pzyon: Yes, I have the access to the parameters. But I want to create a new JSON list variable i.e. employees here and access ONLY that variable in my HTML. However, the data needed to create that variable is in the parameters I have passed i.e. addressData, creditData etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the linker and use the controller attribute of the directive,

```js
controller: (['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.employees = [{
      "firstname": firstname,
      "lastname": lastname
    }];
  }
])
```

This creates the employees data structure.
Pass the function inside the array. Otherwise, if minifier is used, webpack will replace `$scope` by some alphabet. Then it won't work in the production.

If not passed inside the array, you'll get the error [Error Reference/ $injector/ unpr](https://code.angularjs.org/1.8.2/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%20%3C-%20t) in the production environment.

Comment: After I added controller attribute I dont get the above error. but data is not displayed. Below are the changes--->  controller: function($scope){

            $scope.employees=[{}];
            var firstname = "John";
            var lastname = "Smith";
            var employee = {
                "firstname": firstname,
                "lastname": lastname
            }

            $scope.employees.push(employee);


        }

Comment: a good way to check if data is being assigned is to just type {{employees}} in the html. See what it says. I would also make sure that you do an ng-repeat on the row not the table body. Also if writing {{employees}} doesn't work.. try {{$parent.employees}} in the html.. if that works it means you've allocated scope wrong.. I hope that helps... let me know if it doesn't ( Happy coding )

Comment: When I tried putting this logic in the plunker it works like a charm.. but in my application file it does not. its very strange. I moved the ng-repeat to TR as you suggested. Data is still coming as blank for {{employees}}. Also tried $parent.employees.

Comment: Browser was just probably caching something old. Works Great!!!! Thank you very much... Guys like you and BatteryAcid are an asset to the community!!!

Comment: @greengrassbluesky I recommend cacheKiller for chrome. It has saved me a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunker [Example New Variable](http://plnkr.co/edit/DGLzBw?p=preview).

I set it up so that the showData() is called when clicking a link.  I would recommend using your controller only for initialization.  There's no harm in initializing your employees inside the controller like @Carlos suggested, but if it isn't needed then you can create it within the showData method you have in your link.

Directive:

```
<custom></custom>
```

If you are having other issues check your directive setup.

Comment: Thanks for creating plunker! Appreciate it. I dont really understand though how problem is solved. Adding employees in the scope through linker function is printing the data but it is throwing errors in the console. Even in this case, it will throw the errors.

Comment: I don't see any errors from my plunker so maybe you have some other issues.  It's hard to say without seeing all the code.  Can you create a plunker with your code and maybe we can work off that?

Comment: Thanks for the clue! I was able to recreate it in the plunker. changed ng-click to ng-show. can ng-show have a problem with it ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, try moving the ng-show inside the directive template HTML.  I'll take a look at the plunkr later.

Comment: Sorry for last comment, I wasn't at my computer - I updated my plunker link above.  [Updated]http://plnkr.co/edit/DGLzBw?p=preview

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but using one method to return a status that shows/hides an element and also update a scope variable which is used in an ng-repeat seems messy, try breaking it up like in my example.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right its messy... I want to actually create this object employees before the page loads... ideally I dont want to have any trigger events like 'click' or 'show'. For a lack of better way to do, I added it in ng-show.

Comment: Thanks for your support/help... I am using controller attribute as Carlos suggested and it works great...